# NullPointerException array passing through super error

Tags: java, arrays, super

Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int array[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    } 
}
```

Parent class:

```
public class Class1 {
    int array[];

    public Class1(int array[]) {

    }
}
```

Child class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Class2 extends Class1 {
    public Class2 (int array[]) {
        super(array);
        class2();
    }

    public void class2() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        array[2] = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you getting an NPE?  Your main method doesn't even call your other code.

Comment: Your never initialize the array in Class1 with the parameter! In the future, please post real code, not sort-of, kind-of code. Your posted code is not compilable, doesn't make full sense, and only serves to confuse. We can't even be 100% if what we're seeing is the source of your problem.

Comment: Your `Class2` code isn't going to compile, you have a bunch of loose statements that aren't in a method.

Comment: Hey Linus, you really shouldn't edit mistakes out of the OP's code.  That obscures possible problems.  For all we know the broken stuff is what they're actually trying to run.

Comment: @azurefrog And where should the NPE come from if one of his classes won't even compile? He doesn't even use them, but that's another story :D. (edit: oh, he did more than just fixing `publicvoid`, ... darn, missed that).

Comment: @Tom Yeah, but I noticed that later... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

array[] is not set in the constructor of Class1.
Try this:

```
this.array = array;
```

Comment: thank you a lot.. java assigment complete now i can sleep peacefully